# Linear transformation and range

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I recently had a linear algebra exam that had a somewhat complex question that I couldn't wrap my head around. It had four items, but I could only do two of them. I would love it if someone could offer me some ideas on how to solve these other two items.

1. Recall that $C^1(\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R}):=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:\mathrm{such\ that}\ f'(x)\ \mathrm{exists\ for\ all}\ x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$ Define $T$ as
   $$T:C^1(\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\\
   f(x)\rightarrow T(f):=(f'(3),f(3))$$
   a) What is the range of $T$, $R(T)$? Give a basis for $R(T)$.
   b) Let $H:=\{(x-3)^2g(x):g(x)\in C^1(\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R})\}$, and $V:=\{f:T(f)=(a_0,b_0)\}$, for fixed $(a_0,b_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $H+V=V$, where $H+V=\{h+f:h\in H,f\in V\}$.

I would genuinely appreciate it if anyone could offer me some guidance or even a solution to these questions. I know that to find $R(T)$, I can use the fact that
$$R(T)=\mathrm{span}(T(\beta)),$$
where $\beta$ is the basis for $C^1(\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R})$. But I don't know how to continue from this. I can't figure out what $\beta$ is. For my second question, I thought about proving that $H+V\subseteq V$ and $V\subseteq H + V$, but couldn't do it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hi! I edited the question with my ideas so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two questions are very nice. Since these exercises came out of an exam, I think it's more valuable at this point to give you a a guided solution in which you fill in some details rather than solving the questions completely. With that said, let's get started.

$a)$ Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$. Prove that the set $\{T(f), T(g)\}$ is linearly independent. Thus, $R(T)$ admits a linearly independent subset of size 2 and is a subspace of the $2$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. In view of this fact, what is the relationship between $R(T)$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? Can you think of any basis for $R(T)$ under these circumstances?

$b)$ For your second question, let's prove that $H+V\subseteq V$ and $V\subseteq H+V$. The inclusion $V\subseteq H+V$ should be very easy to prove: given $f\in V$, can you come up with $h\in H$ and $g\in V$ in such a way that $f=h+g$? Remember that, in the context of vector spaces, there is always a special element that behaves in a particular way with addition.

Now, in order to prove that $H+V \subseteq V$, fix $h\in H$ and $f\in V$. Let $g$ be in such a way that $h(x)=(x-3)^{2} g(x)$. Our job now is to find $j \in V$ such that $(x-3)^{2} g(x) + f(x) = j(x)$. I claim that if we let $j(x)$ equal $(x-3)^{2} g(x) + f(x)$, then $j$ has the desired properties. To show this, clearly you just have to verify that $T(j)=(a_0,b_0)$. Once you have done this we can conclude that the missing inclusion is true. Therefore, $H+V = V$.

If you need me to elaborate more on any of the points, please, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I will carefully look at your guided solutions and solve these problems. I just have a quick question about your thought process behind item . How did you come up with the idea of using the set {(),()}? Is it because of our codomain ℝ2? Did you use ()= and ()=2 because x and $x^2$ are elements in the standard basis for the polynomials vector space?

Comment: My reasoning for $a)$ was the following: I think that to understand a hard/not-so-easy problem you first need to find out how it interacts with the most basic things you have available and that you understand well. In this case, in view of the domain of $T$, the first thing I tried was to see what the interaction of $T$ was with respect to $f$ and $g$, which were the simplest differentiable functions I could think of. In hindsight, maybe I should've suggested $g$ to be a non-zero constant function to simplify the argument of linear independence, but either $g$ works fine.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much!